# Change description based on boolean value in XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I am new to XML and i am looking to change the description based on Boolean value.

```
<preference name="displaycontent"
                  type="bool" value="false"
                  description="This is false" />
```

if value is true then it should show the description

```
description="This is true"
```

what is the best way to do in XML?
Thanks

Comment: Makes no sense. Show the description in what? A browser, another xml, some application???

Comment: For some application.

Answer (score 0):

XML is not a programming language that can change state of any sort, so it has no means to accomplish your goal – *to change the description based on Boolean value.*

XML is just a data format.

Plenty of programming languages can read and write XML.  XSLT is particularly good at transforming between XML documents.  You'll need to use XSLT or another programming language to accomplish your goal.  XML alone cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

A good language for transforming XML is XSLT. In the latest version of XSLT (3.0) you can do this as:

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="preference[@name='displaycontent']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="description" select="'This is ' || @value"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

With earlier versions of XSLT the code is a bit more verbose, but it's not difficult to achieve.